# If I deploy DACPAC over existing database will it wipe it?

Tags: sql-server

I gave a backup of my SQL-Server database to a vendor, they made changes and sent me back a DACPAC. If I use SQLPackage.exe to deploy that DACPAC to the original database will it wipe the data in my tables?

My understanding is that a DACPAC is just schema. I'm worried my tables will be empty afterwards.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, executing a .dacpac will never cause data loss.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me, the deployment from visual studio dropped the database and re-created. I had enabled "Always re-create database" option in SqlProject properties / Debug left tab. May be helpful for someone